# How to use "Almond" in "RequireJS" to generate one single file?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, almond

I have a project with RequireJS.

My app.build with require :

```
({
    appDir: './',
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "dist",
    mainConfigFile: "js/main.js",
    modules: [ { name: 'main' } ],
    optimizeCss: 'standard',
    removeCombined: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    optimize: "uglify",
    uglify: {
        max_line_length: 1000,
        compress: {
            cascade: true,
            drop_console: true,
            keep_fargs: true
        },
        defines: {
            DEBUG: ['name', 'false']
        },
        no_mangle: true
    },
    closure: {
        CompilerOptions: {},
        CompilationLevel: 'SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS',
        loggingLevel: 'WARNING'
    }
})
```

After compile I have three js files - require.js, main.js, domReady.js
I try to get single file via Almond, I added some parameters:

```
({
            appDir: './',
            baseUrl: "js",
            modules: [
                {
                    name: '../lib/almond/almond'
                },
                {
                    name: 'main'
                }
            ],
            include: ['main'],
            insertRequire: ['main'],
            wrap: true,
            dir: "dist",
            mainConfigFile: "js/main.js",
            optimizeCss: 'standard',
            removeCombined: true,
            preserveLicenseComments: false,
            optimize: "uglify",
            uglify: {
                ...
            },
            closure: {
                ...
            }
})
```

But in the end I still have three files...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
({
    appDir: './',
    baseUrl: "js",
    dir: "dist",
    mainConfigFile: "js/main.js",
    findNestedDependencies: true,
    name: 'main',
    include: ['../lib/almond/almond'],
    insertRequire: ['main'],
    optimizeCss: 'standard',
    removeCombined: true,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    optimize: "uglify",
    uglify: {
...
    },
    closure: {
...
    }
})
```

after compile I have a single file...
Then via GULP I change code in my index.html

```
<script src="lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: how do you change the index file with gulp?

Comment: I mark code like this '<!-- build:js --> <script src="lib/requirejs/require.js" data-main="js/main.js"></script> <!-- endbuild -->' and then change via gulp-html-replace